# Xubuntu 13.10 Wi-Fi Network Dropping

Tags: wireless, networking, xubuntu, intel, netgear

I just installed Xubuntu 13.10 and I am experiencing some odd behavior on my laptop.
Occasionally with no predictable pattern Xubuntu will not be able to find my Wi-Fi network.
Specifically the one I was connected to. All other networks in the area still show up.

When I disable Wireless and enable it again it always finds it without issue, so it's not a crucial issue, but still I have to watch after it like a hawk and I'd rather not go through all the trouble.

It's a dirt-old Gateway, lspci tells me that the ethernet controller is Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection (rev 02), the router is a NetGear N600 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router.

Any help would be awesome.

Update: FIXED, but I can't answer my own question cause I'm new here but here goes:

So after more searching I found out that my particular problem was with network manager. I installed wicd and now my connection isn't dropping anymore. However it came with it's own can of worms as Linux fixes are wont to do.

I had to purge network manager after installing wicd, which was fine, but then wicd wouldn't start until I deleted the link to resolv.conf in /etc/ and copied the file found in /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf into /etc/. For whatever reason the link was not enough. Then I was golden. Hope this fixes similar problems for you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When xubuntu 13.04 was released I had upgraded to it. But as soon as i upgraded, my wifi stopped working. It was showing all the connections, but unable to connect to them. So, I switched back to 12.10.
In your case, at least this version is able to connect (for a while though).
If it is possible, I would suggest you try xubuntu 12.10 or better 12.04, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This would have worked too I'm sure, so I'll mark it as an answer. See my edited OP for the fix for 13.10